# three20 build issues

Tags: iphone, xcode4, three20

I am having issues with building my project with three20. I previously had three20 folder outside of my project folder, then I decided to clone another three20 inside my folder and then re-run the script again. However now when I tried to do import "Three20/Three20.h" it constantly says there's no such file or directory. What should I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may have changed, but I recall with my last Three20/xcode4 experience that you have to change the build directory settings for xcode4 for it work.

In Xcode preferences, go to the locations tab and change the dropdown for build location to "...locations specified by targets"

As I understand it Three20 expects the build directory to be in the same place it was using Xcode3.  No promises, but give it a try.

Comment: Did you do all the usual like setting header search paths for your project?

Comment: hmmm...what should the header search path be? I had it $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../three20 and $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20

Comment: Should be wherever you have Three20, probably $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/three20